# Как поднять репутацию?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, защищённые-вопросы

Ни прокомментировать нигде не дает, ни лайкнуть, чтобы пометить что помогло.
Может где-то купить себе репутацию можно? Дайте ссылку если так. А то в настройках нечего не нашел.

Я вроде активный программист (JS, React, React Native), но когда появляется какой-то вопрос, здесь ответа не находится, и со временем у меня получается разобраться самостоятельно, то я нечего написать не могу, чтобы помочь коллегам. Написано, чтобы защититься от спама. Но тогда дайте задонатить 1-2 бакса, чтобы показать что я не бот.

Надеюсь обьясните как тут начать пользоваться.

Comment: [Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Это я видел, но там нету инфы, можно ли искуственно поднять себе репутацию, хотя-бы до 50, чтобы дать ответ там где хотел это сделать... В этом и была суть проблемы...

Comment: Ответ простой — никак. Поэтому и нет подобной информации.

Comment: Обидно, понял, спасибо :)

Comment: кто то минусанул ....

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ссылку на вопрос, где не получалось дать ответ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [Привилегии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) определяют набор доступных действий на сайте Stack Overflow
>   на русском. Повышая свою репутацию, вы открываете новые привилегии
>   ([репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reputation) — это баллы, которые вы **получаете за публикацию полезных
>   вопросов и ответов**).

Comment: Ну не буду же я писать вопросы, на которые знаю ответ :) А ответить там где я знал, мне не дало... Сказало нужно 50 баллов...

Comment: @ИгорьЧумаченко: наверное потому, что нужно ответ оформлять, а не в комментариях заметки делать.

Comment: хм, видимо я не до конца понял еще как пользоваться сайтом. Нужно будет поковыряться, может действительно это я туплю... Спасибо :)

Comment: @ИгорьЧумаченко: некоторые не знают, некоторым просто лень, а некоторые специально в комментах дают ответ, чтобы минусов не выхватить, если ответ неправильный.

Comment: @ИгорьЧумаченко, отвечать на свои вопросы можно и нужно. На странице вопроса для этого даже есть пункт "Ответить на собственный вопрос". Только убедитесь, что ранее на этот вопрос уже не отвечали.